# как сверстать подобный нетривиальный дизайн border`а элемента?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

как сверстать и сделать резиновым подобный border для input лучшим образом? псевдо элементами, или есть какая то конструкция проще?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ну типо..

```css
body {background: blue;}

input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* corner */
  --cc: #fff; /* corner color */
  --cw: 10px; /* corner width */
  --ch: 3px; /* corner height */
  /* line-border */
  --lc: #fff; /* line color */
  --lw: 1px; /* line width */
  --lh: 3px; /* line height */
  --ls: 10px; /* line step */
  --lot: 0; /* line offset top */
  --lol: 0; /* line offset left */
  /* background */
  --bg: red; /* background color */
  --bgm: 2px; /* background margin */
  
  
  background-image:
    /* corner */
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--cc), var(--cc)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--cc), var(--cc)),
    /* line-border */
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--lc) var(--lw), transparent var(--lw)),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--lc) var(--lw), transparent var(--lw)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--lc) var(--lw), transparent var(--lw)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, var(--lc) var(--lw), transparent var(--lw)),
    /* background */
    linear-gradient(var(--bg), var(--bg));
    
  background-repeat:
    /* corner */
    no-repeat, no-repeat,
    /* line-border */
    repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y,
    /* background */
    no-repeat;
  background-position: 
    /* corner */
    0 0, 0 0,
    /* line-border */
    var(--lol) 0, var(--lol) 100%, 0 var(--lot), 100% var(--lot),
    /* background */
    var(--bgm) var(--bgm);
  background-size: 
    /* corner */
    var(--cw) var(--ch), var(--ch) var(--cw),
    /* line-border */
    var(--ls) var(--lh), var(--ls) var(--lh), var(--lh) var(--ls), var(--lh) var(--ls),
    /* background */
    calc(100% - var(--bgm)*2) calc(100% - var(--bgm)*2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```